# Using marked in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to use marked in reactjs as described in the [reactjs docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#adding-markdown).

```
<div>{marked(mystring)}</div>
```

I use babel so I import marked like this:

```
import { marked } from 'marked';
```

Unfortunately the import statement does not work. marked is not defined.
How do I have to import marked here, so that I can use it?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here's one way to use `marked` with `React`:

1. Ensure that you've installed [`marked`](https://npm.im/marked)
2. Include `marked` in your project's `package.json` file:

```
// package.json
{
  dependencies: {
    react: "^17.0.0",
    marked: "^4.0.0",
  },
}
```

3. Import `marked` in your `.jsx` *(or related)* file:

```js
import { marked } from "marked";
```

4. Use the [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) approach as shown in the example below:

```js
import React from "react";
import { marked } from "marked";

class MarkdownExample extends React.Component {
  getMarkdownText() {
    var rawMarkup = marked.parse("This is _Markdown_.");
    return { __html: rawMarkup };
  }
  render() {
    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.getMarkdownText()} />;
  }
}
```

The [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) attribute gives you the ability to work with raw (HTML) markup. Make sure to [take care when using this attribute](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml), though!

#### Alternative (Safe)

If you don't want to use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) and safely render HTML. Try [marked-react](https://npm.im/marked-react), which internally uses [`marked`](https://npm.im/marked) to render the html elements as react components

```sh
npm i marked-react
```

```js
import Markdown from "marked-react";

const MarkdownComponent = () => {
  return <Markdown>{rawmarkdown}</Markdown>;
};
```

Another alternative is [react-markdown](https://npm.im/react-markdown)

---

Comment: Please change the npm library from 'react-marked' to just 'marked' in point no. 1. Lost a lot of time due to that.

Answer (score 3):

With the marked-wrapper [react-marked-markdown](https://github.com/vincent-p/react-marked-markdown):

```
import { MarkdownPreview } from 'react-marked-markdown'

export default ({ post }) => (
  <div>
    <h1>{ post.title }</h1>
    <MarkdownPreview value={ post.content }/>
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way of using [marked](https://marked.js.org/) with React Hooks:

> 1. Create your MarkedConverter component

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import marked from 'marked'

export const MarkedConverter = () => {
  const [markedVal, setMarkedVal] = useState(
    '# Welcome to my React Markdown Previewer!'
  )
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkUp(markedVal)}></div>
}
```

> 2. Create Markup function and pass the value from MarkedConverter Component

```
export const createMarkUp = (val) => {
 return { __html: marked(val) }
}
```

> 3. Finally you can import MarkedConverter Component to any of your Component

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to import marked:

```
import marked from 'marked';
```

Then call the function in your component:

```
marked('# Markdown');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example on how to use marked with react:

1. Install marked with NPM : npm i marked
2. import it in your react app (this example is created with create-react-app), and using it
   [example of a react component using "marked"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XD1l6.png)
3. result in the browser :
   [preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yf3dB.png)