# Using a string as input with reactDOM.render, marked.js and babel

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So I am attempting to build a git markdown previewer using React, babel and marked.js. Marked.js is a markdown parser.

So say I have a value that I want to use from my html.

```
<div id="markdownInput"># This is my input</div>
```

In javascript, I store it as the variable myInput.

```
var myInput = document.getElementById("markdownInput").value;
```

myInput is now "# This is my input" and is a string. Marked.js uses a function called "marked()" that takes a string as input and converts the git markdown to html.

```
var myOutput = marked(myInput);
```

myOutput is now equal to:

```
"<h1>This is my input</h1>"
```

Notice that the markdown is converted (# =>h1) but it is also stored as a string. If I attempt to use this with reactDOM.render like so:

```
ReactDOM.render(myOutput, document.getElementById("output-container"));
```

My "output-container" in my HTML ends up with displaying:

```
<h1>This is my input</h1>
```

rather than displaying "**This is my input**" in large header letters. What it boils down to is that React.DOM.render() needs an object as input and not a string. It needs:

```
<h1>This is my input</h1>
```

As an object but I am inputting it as a string because the marked() function only outputs as a string (which wraps everything in quotes).

Is there anything that I can do to convert myOutput to an object? I am extremely knew to React so perhaps I haven't learned a better method for something like this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, found this [Using marked in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34686523/using-marked-in-react) and used the "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" attribute. Is there perhaps a better way to do this though?

Comment: This is the way. And as it states, it's really dangerous to do that, especially in this example where you can input whatever you want.